# Чего-то не так с регулярными выражениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой вот код:

```
    <div class="s-prose js-post-body" itemprop="text">
        <p>I'm new to Machine learning i got 1 example of Cat vs Dog image classification
        and here is the link to it </p>
        <p><a href="https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-kats-vs-dogs-machine-learning-tutorial/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-kats-vs-dogs-machine-learning-tutorial/</a> </p>
        <p>It worked perfectly , but now when i want to implement transfer learning to it using VGG16 , it's not working  </p>

        <!-- Начало первого элемента -->
        <pre class="lang-py s-code-block hljs python"><code><span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras.models <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> Sequential, Model, load_model
            <span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras.applications.vgg16 <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> VGG16

            <span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> optimizers
            <span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras.layers <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation

            <span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras.models <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> Sequential
            <span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> utils

            train = train_data[:-<span class="hljs-number">500</span>]
            test = train_data[-<span class="hljs-number">500</span>:]

            X = np.array([i[<span class="hljs-number">0</span>] <span class="hljs-keyword">for</span> i <span class="hljs-keyword">in</span> train]).reshape(-<span class="hljs-number">1</span>,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,<span class="hljs-number">3</span>)
            Y = [i[<span class="hljs-number">1</span>] <span class="hljs-keyword">for</span> i <span class="hljs-keyword">in</span> train]

            test_x = np.array([i[<span class="hljs-number">0</span>] <span class="hljs-keyword">for</span> i <span class="hljs-keyword">in</span> test]).reshape(-<span class="hljs-number">1</span>,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,<span class="hljs-number">3</span>)
            test_y = np.array([i[<span class="hljs-number">1</span>] <span class="hljs-keyword">for</span> i <span class="hljs-keyword">in</span> test])

            <span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras.layers <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> Activation, Conv2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
            <span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> keras.models <span class="hljs-keyword">import</span> Sequential


            modelvgg = VGG16(weights=<span class="hljs-string">'imagenet'</span>, include_top=<span class="hljs-literal">False</span>, input_shape=(<span class="hljs-number">50</span>,<span class="hljs-number">50</span>,<span class="hljs-number">3</span>))
            <span class="hljs-built_in">type</span>(modelvgg)
            modelvgg.layers.pop()
            model = Sequential()
            <span class="hljs-keyword">for</span> layer <span class="hljs-keyword">in</span> modelvgg.layers:
            model.add(layer)

            <span class="hljs-keyword">for</span> layer <span class="hljs-keyword">in</span> model.layers:
            layer.trainable = <span class="hljs-literal">False</span> 

            model.add(Dense(<span class="hljs-number">1</span>, activation= <span class="hljs-string">'sigmoid'</span>))



            model.<span class="hljs-built_in">compile</span>(optimizer=<span class="hljs-string">'adam'</span>, learning_rate=LR, loss=<span class="hljs-string">'categorical_crossentropy'</span>, name=<span class="hljs-string">'targets'</span>)
            model.summary()


            model.fit({<span class="hljs-string">'input'</span>: X}, {<span class="hljs-string">'targets'</span>: Y}, n_epoch=<span class="hljs-number">10</span>, validation_set=({<span class="hljs-string">'input'</span>: test_x}, {<span class="hljs-string">'targets'</span>: test_y}), 
            snapshot_step=<span class="hljs-number">500</span>, show_metric=<span class="hljs-literal">True</span>, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
            </code>
        </pre>
        <!-- Конец первого элемента -->

        <p>Here is the Error i always get</p>
        <p>I guess there's a problem i guess of how i'm fitting my module so please i need help with that </p>

        <!-- Начало второго элемента -->
        <pre class="lang-py s-code-block hljs python"><code>Unrecognized keyword arguments: {<span class="hljs-string">'n_epoch'</span>: <span class="hljs-number">10</span>, <span class="hljs-string">'validation_set'</span>: ({<span class="hljs-string">'input'</span>: array([[[[ <span class="hljs-number">41</span>,  <span class="hljs-number">40</span>,  <span class="hljs-number">36</span>],
            [ <span class="hljs-number">43</span>,  <span class="hljs-number">42</span>,  <span class="hljs-number">38</span>],
            [ <span class="hljs-number">43</span>,  <span class="hljs-number">42</span>,  <span class="hljs-number">38</span>],
            </code>
        </pre>
        <!-- Конец второго элемента -->

    </div>
```

Я пытаюсь отформатировать его, вырезав тег `<pre>` и все что в нем есть, с помощью метода `re.sub()`.

Вот как я пишу:

`re.sub(r'<pre.*?>.*?</pre>', '', s, re.S)`

И ничего не получается. Я попробовал просто найти эти элементы через `re.findall()` и тут все получается, хотя использовал я то же самое регулярное выражение:

`re.findall(r'<pre.*?>.*?</pre>', s, re.S)`

Возвращаются нужные элементы, их 2.

В чем ошибка с методом `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 2):

Синтаксис функции:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Вы вызываете её как:

```
re.sub(r'<pre.*?>.*?</pre>', '', s, re.S)
```

Получается, что вы передали флаг `re.S` в аргумент `count` вместо `flags`. Просто явно укажите имя аргумента, если вам `count` без надобности:

```
re.sub(r'<pre.*?>.*?</pre>', '', s, flags=re.S)
```

Comment: Как показывает практика, на такие обидные ошибки уходит больше всего времени)